# How to keep audio playing when extension popup is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to figure out how to make my Chrome extension audio keep playing after the popup.html is closed.
Please help, thank you.

I tried reading another question similar to this one but ended up with no results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't embed the player in the pop-up, put it in the background page.
Use localStorage (or chrome.storage) to save data.
Another option is to pass messages to the background page. This can generally be done using message passing. In pop-ups, it's much easier to use

Use chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()

```
 // popup.js:
var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
// On load?
var data = background.saved_data;

// ... Later, when data changes, update data:
background.saved_data = data;
```